# How to find a specific colour in the range and then if cell is = "" put value 0 and keep the the same colour in the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I recently started playing with VBA and I try al I could to figure it out but without the success.

Basically what I would like to do is to find a colour in the range and then if the cell is blank, I would like to put value 0 and keep the colour.

Below is the code I created but it is not working on `"If PCell.Value = "" Then"`

```
Sub ColorCell()
    PCell = RGB(255, 204, 204)

    range("A:F").Select

    For Each cell In Selection
        If cell.Interior.Color = PCell Then
            If PCell.Value = "" Then
                Set cell.Value = 0
            End If
         End If        
    Next
End Sub
```

Below is an example of how the spreadsheet.

[image: Example]

I would really appreciate your help. I spent all day browsing and trying but no luck :(

Comment: How is the color added? Manually or by Conditional Formatting?

Comment: Thank you for looking into it, I already have a solution for it from Error 1004.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has some issues:

- `Set` should be used only on objects (like `Worksheets` or `Range)`
- you test `PCell.Value` instead of `cell.Value`

Here is the working code:

```
Sub ColorCell()
    PCell = RGB(255, 204, 204)

    Range("A:F").Select

    For Each cell In Selection
        If cell.Interior.Color = PCell Then
            If cell.Value = "" Then
                cell.Value = 0
            End If
         End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for thh tips, all make sense. It worked, however, for some reason Excel was crashing after I run the macro. I used the solution from Error 1004 below.

Comment: great, glad you found a solution, don't forget to accept the solution you chose and to upvote (when you have the privileges) the answers that helped you

Comment: Just to add a bit, I think it was crashing because the last row was not set and I have a lot of data to go through. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row '<- Get the last row of column F to avoid looping all the column

        Set rng = .Range("A1:F" & LastRow) '<- Set the range from A1 to F last row

        For Each cell In rng

            If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 204) And cell.Value = "" Then
                cell.Value = 0
            End If

        Next cell

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant, it worked as expected! Thank you very much, I really appreciate quick response!!

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
If PCell.Value = "" Then
```

with:

```
If Cell.Value = "" Then
```

Replace:

```
Set cell.Value = 0
```

with:

```
cell.Value = 0
```

Also avoid Select:

```
Sub ColorCell()
    Dim PCell As Variant, Intersection As Range, Cell As Range
    PCell = RGB(255, 204, 204)

    Set Intersection = Intersect(Range("A:F"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

    If Not Intersection Is Nothing Then
        For Each Cell In Intersection
            If Cell.Interior.Color = PCell Then
                If Cell.Value = "" Then
                    Cell.Value = 0
                End If
             End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

*(there may be other errors in the code)*

Comment: Thank you very much. Very useful tips!

Answer (score 0):

`PCell` is not `cell`

```
Sub ColorCell()
    PCell = RGB(255, 204, 204)

    For Each cell In intersect(ActiveSheet.usedrange, range("A:F"))
        If cell.Interior.Color = PCell and cell.Value = "" Then
            cell.Value = 0
        End If        
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Might want to use `intersect(usedrange, range("A:F")).Select` or you're looping down to the last row twice.

Comment: Would this be a nice addition? > `For Each cell In Intersect(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks))`? with `If cell.Interior.Color = PCell Then cell.Value = 0`

Comment: @JvdV you would need some more lines. If `SpecialCells` returns `Nothing` you need to test for it otherwise `Intersect` fails.

Comment: That's correct :) @ Peh, It might not be worth the hassle then (unless it's a ton of unnessacry cells to loop through )

Comment: @JvdV well it might reduce your loop time a lot if you have a lot of data but only little blanks in it. So it could be worth to reduce runtime to a minimum.

Comment: Thank you very for your post, it is very helpful and I really appreciate, however, it gives an error. in "" For Each cell In Intersect(UsedRange, range("A:F")).Select". I already used formula from Error 1004. :D